# Prove that there exists $\lambda>1$ such that $f \geq \lambda g$ in $[a, b]$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f, g:[a, b] \rightarrow(0, \infty)$ be continuous functions such that $g(x)<f(x)$ for all $x \in[a, b]$. Prove that there exists $\lambda>1$ such that $f \geq \lambda g$ in $[a, b]$.

---

My solution: Let $h=f/g$, hence $h$ is continuous in the closed interval $[a,b]$, so it must attain it's minimum (say $m$). Let $h \geq m >1$ (as $f>g$). Hence, $f \geq mg$, and $m > 1$, so $\lambda =m$.
The reason I am not sure about the validity of my solution is that the solution given in my book is entirely different and rather uses sequences (if anyone asks, I will try to edit this post adding the solution). Can anyone please confirm if it's ok?

Comment: Yes, this is fine, and certainly more elegant than a sequential argument.